# Exchange Web Services EWS Returns ErrorNonExistentMailbox for 365 accounts

Tags: exchangewebservices

We are using Hybrid setup with on-prem mailboxes and some that are migrated to 365.
We are using on-prem EWS from the application to access user calendars.
It works with on-prem users, but when access 365 users, we get ErrorNonExistentMailbox.
They are licensed so that wouldn't be the issue there.
The exact error is below, and the Guid doesn't look right.

```
           <m:CreateItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
               <m:MessageText>No mailbox with such guid.</m:MessageText>
               <m:ResponseCode>ErrorNonExistentMailbox</m:ResponseCode>
               <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
               <m:MessageXml>
                  <t:Value Name="MailboxGuid">S-1-5-21-313343422-1840124433-.....</t:Value>
               </m:MessageXml>
               <m:Items/>
            </m:CreateItemResponseMessage>
```

Contacted MS support and was passed between on-prem and online support teams, no solution.
Used https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/ to verify, same error.

Answer (score 1):

> It works with on-prem users, but when access 365 users, we get ErrorNonExistentMailbox

Are you using Hybrid Modern Authentication ? if so which authentication flow are you using ?

You need to treat these as two separate systems and do a discover to work out which users are online and which are OnPrem then adjust the EWS url and authentication accordingly and if you are using Hybrid Modern Auth you also need to make sure the Audience of the token is also set appropriately. Based on the error your getting it look like your trying to access the O365 users using the onPrem EWS endpoint which won't work you always need to use https://outlook.office365.com/exchange.asmx for these users. Note depending on your internal DNS config if your relying on Autodiscover that may not work you should look at autodiscoverv2 in that instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The application uses EWS with impersonation. The impersonating user is authenticated with basis authentication. So if we have to hit different urls depending on where the user's mailbox is, how do I handle the meetings where users and invitees are on both 365 and on-prem? Can the 365 EWS handle all? We may need to figure out how to hit that, don't know what credentials to use yet.

Comment: For Office365 you won't be able to use Basic authentication so you will need oauth for o365 users. EWS always works in the context of a Mailbox if that mailbox is onPrem you need different auth,a different Endpoint if the user is o365 then you will need a different context as well. You won't be able to access both o365 and onPrem within the same authentication/ewsURL context so you need to design around that. For meetings it should work okay if you inviting both onPrem and o365 users as a correctly configured hybrid Org will handle that. Its just you won't be able to access both mailboxes